# Saving location exif data with photo in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, image, gps, exif

I am building an app that needs to take a photo and save it to the library with GPS information and a timestamp.

Everything seems to be working, including the code to add the location metadata (all successful messages in the debug window).

However, when I check the photo's properties, there is no location metadata.

```js
var locManager = CLLocationManager();
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func addPhotoFromCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    locManager.startUpdatingLocation();
    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        print("LOCATION SERVICES DISABLED");
        return;
    }    
    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController();
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera;
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil);
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () in
        if picker.sourceType == .Camera {
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage;
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil);
        }
    });
}

func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo: UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    if didFinishSavingWithError != nil {
        print("Error saving photo: \(didFinishSavingWithError)");
    }
    else {
        print("Successfully saved photo, will make request to update asset metadata");
        // fetch the most recent image asset
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions();
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)];
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions);
            
        // get the asset we want to modify from results
        let lastImageAsset = fetchResult.lastObject as! PHAsset;
        //self.photoImageView.image = getAssetThumbnail(lastImageAsset);
        
        // get location
        var myLocation = CLLocation();
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways) {
            myLocation = locManager.location!;
        }
            
        // make change request
        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
            // modify existing asset
            let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: lastImageAsset);
            assetChangeRequest.location = myLocation;
            },
            completionHandler: {
                (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if success {
                    print("Successfully saved metadata to asset");
                    print("Location metadata = \(myLocation)");
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    print("Failed to save metadata to asset with error: \(error!)");
                    return;
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you check photo's properties? Do you export photo from your device and check it on your computer? If so, how do export photos? I'm asking because if you use AirDrop to transmit photos from your device, iOS sometimes strips out all privacy sensitive information from photos. I had this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location data like this;

```
  let assetResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [localId], options: nil) as PHFetchResult

            guard let asset = assetResult.firstObject else{

                return

            }

            print(asset.location ?? CLLocation())
```